# Loading Nested Models from Checkpoints in PyTorch Lightning

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm dealing with a situation where I have a primary model that contains another model nested within it. The structure of my code is as follows:

```py
def PrimaryModel(..):
   def init(...)
      nested_model=NestedModel(nested_model_ckpt_path,...)
      self.mlp1 = nested_model.mlp1
      self.mlp2 = nested_model.mlp2
```

When I attempt to use `PrimaryModel.load_from_checkpoint(primary_model_ckpt_path)`, an error occurs during the initialization of `NestedModel` because it can't find its `nested_model_ckpt_path`. I'm not passing this path because I'm loading `PrimaryModel` from its own checkpoint.

Additionally, I've confirmed that the state dictionary from the `PrimaryModel` checkpoint contains the information for `mlp1` and `mlp2`:

```py
state_dict=torch.load(cfg.primary_model_ckpt_path)["state_dict"]
```

I'm looking for a clean way to load the nested `NestedModel` from the `PrimaryModel` checkpoint, since it contains all the necessary information for both models. Any guidance on how I should modify my code to handle this properly would be greatly appreciated.